# Include the results of an analysis (for instance ANOVA) in a gwidget

Tags: r, gwidgets

I'm developing an application for simulating experiments and I need to know how to include the result of an analysis (say ANOVA) into a gwidget area. I can deal with plots (including ggplots), but I cannot find how to manage the output of an analysis.

I'll apprciate any suggestion.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @spacedman's answer is spot on. You likely want to use a monospace font. Something like this pattern: `insert(t, capture.output(a), font=list(family="monospace"))` where `t` is a `gtext` object and `a` your object to display.

Answer (score 0):

The help for any analysis function should tell you what it returns, or how to access that information. For example, a glm:

```
> d=data.frame(x=1:10,z1=runif(10),z2=(1:10)+rnorm(10,0,1))
> g = glm(x~z1+z2,data=d)
```

then

```
> summary(g)$coeff
             Estimate Std. Error    t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 0.3875693  0.7895574 0.49086906 0.6385324013
z1          0.1182509  1.8060941 0.06547326 0.9496278349
z2          0.9490186  0.1665428 5.69834785 0.0007366074
```

which is really just a matrix:

```
> ms = summary(g)$coeff
> ms[1,]
  Estimate Std. Error    t value   Pr(>|t|) 
 0.3875693  0.7895574  0.4908691  0.6385324
```

so you can get the values and put them in your widgets as text, or if your widget toolkit has a grid component, one of those.

Or if you just want the text output, use `capture.output`:

```
txt = capture.output(summary(g))
```

and that gives you a vector of text lines that you can put into a widget toolkit text area.

Comment: Another option would be to use `gridExtra`'s `grid.table`. `grid.table(coef(summary(lm.D9)))`.